# Execution plan of table in cluster expects one row when it should expect multiple

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I have created a cluster and a table in the cluster with the following definitions:

```sql
create cluster roald_dahl_titles (
   title varchar2(100)
);

create index i_roald_dahl_titles
on cluster roald_dahl_titles
;

create table ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS (
   title varchar2(100),
   published_year number
)
cluster roald_dahl_titles (title)
;
```

Notably, this is index is not created with the unique constraint, and it's quite possible to insert duplicate values into the table ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS:

```sql
insert into roald_dahl_novels (title, published_year) values ('Esio Trot', 1990);
insert into roald_dahl_novels (title, published_year) values ('Esio Trot', 1990);
```

I then gather statistics on the both the table and the index, and look at an execution plan that uses the index:

```sql
begin
  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS');
  dbms_stats.gather_INDEX_stats(user, 'I_ROALD_DAHL_TITLES');
end;
/

explain plan for
select published_year
  from roald_dahl_novels
 where title = 'Esio Trot';

select *
  from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'ALL'));
```

The contents of the execution plan I find a bit confusing, though:

```
Plan hash value: 2187850431

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                     |     2 |    28 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER| ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS   |     2 |    28 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN  | I_ROALD_DAHL_TITLES |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS@SEL$1
   2 - SEL$1 / ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS@SEL$1

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("TITLE"='Esio Trot')

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS".ROWID[ROWID,10], "TITLE"[VARCHAR2,100], 
       "PUBLISHED_YEAR"[NUMBER,22]
   2 - "ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS".ROWID[ROWID,10]
```

As part of operation 2, it performs an index unique scan, which tells me that 'Esio Trot' is expected to appear only once in the cluster. The execution plan also says that for that operation, it expects to return only one row.

The column projection information tells me that it expects to return a single column (which will be a ROWID for the table ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS), so this tells me that the total number of ROWIDs returned from that operation will be 1 (1 row at 1 ROWID per row). Since each of the two rows in the table ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS has a different ROWID, then this operation can only be used to return a single row from the table.

When the TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER operation is performed, the execution plan then (correctly) expects two rows to be returned, which is what I find confusing. If these rows are being accessed by ROWID, then I would expect the previous operation to return (at least) two ROWIDs. If they are not being accessed by ROWID, I would not expect the previous operation to return and ROWIDs.

Also, in the TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER, the ROWID of the table ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS is listed in the column projection information section. I am not attempting to select the ROWID, so I would not expect it to be returned from that operation. If anywhere, I would expect it to be in the predicate information section.

**Additional investigation**

I tried inserting the same row into the table repeatedly, until it contained 65536 identical copies of the same row. After gathering stats and querying USER_INDEXES for the index I_ROALD_DAHL_TITLES, we got the following:

```
UNIQUENESS  DISTINCT_KEYS   AVG_DATA_BLOCKS_PER_KEY
UNIQUE      1               109
```

As I understand it, this tells us:

- The index is unique, so we expect each key to appear once in the index
- The index has only one distinct key ('Esio Trot'), so must have exactly one entry
- The index expects our one key to match to several rows in the table, across 109 blocks

This seems paradoxical - for one key to match to several rows in the table would mean that there must be several entries in the index for that key (each matching to a different ROWID), which would contradict the index being unique.

When checking USER_EXTENTS, the index only uses a single extent of 65536 bytes, which is not enough space to hold information for each of the ROWIDs in the table.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Even if it has ROWID added to make it unique, it still can't have an entry for every row in the table, or it would take up more space than USER_EXTENTS is describing

Comment: I thought my comment would be confusing / was incomplete, so I deleted it and have written an answer.

Comment: I have to say I'm impressed to see a question about clusters. I've been using Oracle for 30 years and this is the first time anybody has used one.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson It's more of a proof of concept than a major project - I have multiple tables that represent data that exists at the same level and have lots of overlapping columns, but are calculated at different times and would be unsuitable for storing in a single wide table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug.

Run this query in your database:

```
select UNIQUENESS from dba_indexes where index_name = upper('i_roald_dahl_titles');
```

> ```
> UNIQUENES
> ---------
> UNIQUE
> ```

The reason for this is that **B-tree cluster indexes only store the database block address of the cluster block that stores that data** -- it does not store full `rowid` values, like a normal index would.

So, while your various rows for `title = 'Esio Trot'` might have `rowid` values like:

```
select rowid row_id, title from roald_dahl_novels n;
```

> ```
> ROW_ID             TITLE                                                                                               
> ------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ABocNnACmAABWsWAAL Esio Trot                                                                                           
> ABocNnACmAABWsWAAM Esio Trot                                                                                           
> ABocNnACmAABWsWAAN Esio Trot
> ```

The B-tree cluster index only stores one entry: "Esio Trot", with the corresponding database block address.  You can confirm this in your database with:

```
select num_rows from dba_indexes where index_Name = 'I_ROALD_DAHL_TITLES';
```

> ```
>    NUM_ROWS
>  ----------
>           1
> ```

That is why you are getting an `UNIQUE SCAN` reported.  Because that is what it is doing, as far as the index is concerned.

Comment: So the index unique scan is returning a single row, which the column projection information tells us is a single ROWID for the table ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS. How does this allow it to fetch two rows from the table in the next operation?

Comment: The database block address supplied by the cluster index is sufficient for Oracle to locate the correct block(s) in the cluster (in the `TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER` plan step).  Since you have no further filter conditions, the results include any records in those blocks.  It is the nature of clusters that rows not satisfying the index condition would not be stored in those database blocks.

Comment: And just to clarify, the `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN`, is not returning "a single row".  It is returning a single database block address for the block in your cluster.  There could be several rows in that block, but your cluster index doesn't know / doesn't care.

Comment: So is this the process happening behind the scenes?

 - Use the index I_ROALD_DAHL_TITLES to find the address of a single block in ROALD_DAHL_TITLES
 - Access this block in ROALD_DAHL_TITLES by that address
 - This block contains the ROWID of each of the rows in ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS
 - Each of the rows in ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS is accessed by ROWID

Comment: For a _cluster_, that is basically the process -- except for the last sentence: "Each of the rows in ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS is accessed by ROWID".  The block in the cluster is accessed by its database block address.  The individual rows are then just read out of the block in order.  The `ROWID` of each row in the block is not known ahead of time, nor is it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same issue with the actual execution plan (tested in 19.5).
Maybe it is a limitation or bug of the displayed execution plan for cluster objects. I would ask this question on asktom.oracle.com to have some kind of official (and free) answer from Oracle.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  f41cf1x2zdyyr, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select published_year   from roald_dahl_novels  where title = 'Esio
Trot'

Plan hash value: 2187850431

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name        | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |               |      1 |        |       |     1 (100)|      |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER| ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS   |      1 |      2 |    28 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN  | I_ROALD_DAHL_TITLES |      1 |      1 |       |     0   (0)|      |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS@SEL$1
   2 - SEL$1 / ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS@SEL$1

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("TITLE"='Esio Trot')

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS".ROWID[ROWID,10], "TITLE"[VARCHAR2,100], "PUBLISHED_YEAR"[NUMBER,22]
   2 - "ROALD_DAHL_NOVELS".ROWID[ROWID,10]


32 rows selected.
```